# How to integrate Storybook with Laravel Jetstream + Inertia?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, storybook

I made a project scaffolding script from the official laravel one, you can check the next steps to reproduce my issue:

⚠️FOR YOUR SECURITY ALWAYS READ UNKWOWN SCRIPTS BEFORE USING THEM⚠️

Create an example Laravel project with Laravel Sail + Jetstream Inertia with Teams support and Storybook

#### Scaffold a project with this sript

`curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/moracabanas/d264f9b2c6b7d9de6b0b56a091e1cf2d/raw/7fdc986378aa55fd329afd9d02f6d88aa80911ad/jetstream-storybook.sh | bash`

Wait until finishes then

`cd example-app`

Run the laravel stack with Sail
`./vendor/bin/sail up -d`

Compile resources
`./vendor/bin/sail npm run dev`

Then you can visit `localhost` and you are good to go.

### How to stop Laravel Sail stack

`./vendor/bin/sail down`

### How to run Storybook

You must edit `docker-compose.yml` file and map the default Storybook ports `- '6006:6006'` like this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
++          - '6006:6006'          
...
```

This way Storybook ports are exposed to the machine, otherwise Storybook wont be reachable from `localhost:6006`

You must `./vendor/bin/sail up -d` to let docker picking up those new port definition changes from `docker-compose.yml`

And then run Storybook with `sail npm run storybook`

## The issue: Tailwind is not working on Storybook

### Progress

- ✔️ Jetstream uses Webpack 5. Use Storybook build [for webpack 5](https://storybook.js.org/blog/storybook-for-webpack-5/)
- ✔️ Jetstream uses PostCSS 8. Use storybook PostCSS addon and configure it like [here](https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-postcss)
- ❌ Laravel imports `tailwind` and `postcss-import` with the following `webpack.mix.config`:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ])
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Where **tailwind** and **postcss-import** are loaded. I do not understand why it is not using **autoprefixer** nor what is *postcss-import*. I cannot find any documentation for this stack.

So I tried to load them on Storybook with the next `postcss.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        'postcss-import': {},
    },
}
```

But it isn't loading in storybook.

**This is why I think Tailwind isn't working in Storybook**

```
    info @storybook/vue3 v6.4.0-alpha.22
    info 
    info => Loading presets
    info => Loading 1 config file in "/var/www/html/.storybook"
    info => Loading 9 other files in "/var/www/html/.storybook"
    info => Adding stories defined in "/var/www/html/.storybook/main.js"
    info => Using PostCSS preset with postcss@8.3.6
    ------------ nothing here ------------
    info => Using default Webpack5 setup
```

Now back in default webpack 4 Storybook build **you can clearly see `postcss.config.js` is loaded** but webpack 4 build is incompatible:

```
    info @storybook/vue3 v6.4.0-alpha.22
    info 
    info => Cleaning outputDir: /var/www/html/storybook-static
    info => Loading presets
    info => Compiling manager..
    info => Compiling preview..
    info => Loading 1 config file in "/var/www/html/.storybook"
    info => Using implicit CSS loaders
    info => Using custom postcss.config.js
    info => Using default Webpack4 setup
    ERR! Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude)
```

So the last step I am missing is importing Tailwind and Postcss in Storybook the same way Laravel is doing it.

Comment: it's most likely a problem with webpack.mix.js and webpack config under .storybook/main.js (depends on storybook edition). I'm facing "Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema" but it's mainly because having different configs within an application overall.